# What do E1, E2, E3, E4 means in Convex hull algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

I am researching about the fast performed Convex hull algorithm and I encountered S-CH algorithm showing the results having fastest performance between conventional convex hull algorithms.

You can read the article from here. Here is a link
http://meshfree.zcu.cz/data/doc/ConvexHull%20%5BSIBGRAPI_2016%5D.pdf

Also, I found that there are not many articles about this argorithm. Why is it not popular like conventional ones?

Comment: *Ei* is the i-dimensional affine space. Just because the paper says it is faster than others does not mean it really is. SIBGRAPI is a quite low-tier conference. One might assume that the authors would have chosen a more prestigious venue if their algorithm was robust and consistently better than others.

Comment: The proposed method is only a heuristic for early rejection of internal points. The behavior of such heuristics is highly dependent on the distribution of the points and in the extreme cases, they slow down the algorithm. If you have many internal points, I recommend to find the extreme vertices in the four or height cardinal directions and discard the points inside the quadrilateral (resp. octagon). Then https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain